# __NSAutoreleaseNoPool Thrown in SWING Application

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm really dumbfounded here (or maybe just "dumb").  I'm building a simple Java Swing application on my relatively new Mac using the JRE System Library (JVM Contents (MacOS X Default), Hibernate 3.0, and MigLayout with in Eclipse Helios.  Things were going well until I started seeing the following error messages that prevents the GUI from even rendering.

```
2011-02-12 09:40:27.842 java[809:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2011-02-12 09:40:27.843 java[809:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
2011-02-12 09:41:08.355 java[809:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1001575c0 of class NSConcreteMapTableValueEnumerator autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

The first two lines are thrown when I instantiate a JButton using this simple code:

```
 private JButton button = new JButton();
```

The last line is thrown at the conclusion of calling my Controller constructor in Main().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         // Creates a model of the system logic.
    LeapsAndBoundsModel model = new LeapsAndBoundsModel();

        // Creaties a view for the system logic.
    LeapsAndBoundsView leapsAndBoundsView = new LeapsAndBoundsView();

        // Creates a controller that links the two.
    LeapsAndBoundsController controller = new LeapsAndBoundsController(model, leapsAndBoundsView);
      }
```

I've Googled this issue and found lots of people that are having the same problem, but nearly all of them are coding using the CocoaComponent for iPhone application.  This is a simple GUI that uses Hibernate to persist information to a localized Derby database.

I've tried both the following suggestions without success:

```
//Set the CocoaComponent CompatibilityMode to "False"
System.setProperty( "com.apple.eawt.CocoaComponent.CompatibilityMode", "false" );

// Use the "invokeLater" method within Main() construct
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                 doIt();
            }       
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post a full self-contained code example that generates this error? Just a single class with a main method that creates a JFrame and adds the JButton and anything else needed to generate the error messages. This will make it easier for us to find and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, do you have Swing displayed within Eclipse?
Because these errors are generally bugs in SWT (used by Eclipse). cf bugs like:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=211361 and 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=106619

You could try upgrading eclipse, or check the parameters you use to launch Eclipse.